# Why it is very hard to make UI with xamarin forms

Tags: cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I'm working fully in Xamarin Classic iOS and Android. But I tried Xamarin.Forms since past 2 months. It's very hard for me to create UI. I don't know that is just me or someone else is also facing. I know there is some library like Xamarin-Labs,etc... Also there is custom renderer. But if I have to create custom rendered even in so called Cross - Platform (don't hate me, I'm in love with Xamarin) then it is pitty thing. Also it is taking so much time to create simple UI(This is because I'm new to it), but is there any way to create things easy for developers with Xamarin.Forms? I saw there are lots of app created with Xamarin.Forms with actually cool and complex UI. It is very easy to create app with Classic Xamarin. The only problem I'm facing is code sharing. So guys please help me with Xamarin.Forms, is it good for any production application(with complex ui, I know Xamarin doesn't suggest it for complex UI, but I know the dev community.) So need you help to sharper my blade with Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: yea it can be really tough to do anything beyond basic layouts. I've given up on using .xaml files at all. The intellisense doesn't work, there's no graphical designer so you can't check what you've done without loading to device/emulator. I'd suggest doing UI programmatically and expecting to have to custom render at least half your classes. Things I can't do with forms: text align a button, underline text, use a colour gradient, work with bitmaps, upgrade xamarin without spending days fixing things. I'm starting to feel like I'd be better off avoiding forms UI entirely and doing UI natively

Comment: As per respected devs this question is based on opinion, but I think that it is clear that Forms is very bad at complex ui creation.I know that it tends to create Native UI for platform. This is based on we can't customise Entry and button. There is a library also called NControl to create amazing UI. Anyway I want to collect info and want to learn Xamarin.Forms without creating Custom Renderer.

Answer (score 1):

You know Xamarin forms is not intended to do complex UI, for complex UI You must use Xamarin.iOS/Android, nevertheless if this is not the question here are some tutorials for simply and beautiful UI:

https://www.syntaxismyui.com/category/xamarin-forms/inanger-xamarin-forms/

http://blog.twintechs.com/advanced-xamarin-forms-techniques-for-flexible-and-performant-cross-platform-apps-part-5-page-in-page-embedding

And If you don't like to code UI and want to spend money then:

http://grialkit.com/